# Django problems with apache2 mod_wsgi, _sql import error

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I'm struggling to run an apache2 server for django. I wanted to try gunicorn, but as I expect apache to be installed in in workplaces more frequently, so I'll stick to it.
Problem currently lies (I think) in an Import Error visible in the excerpt from apache error.log. I've tried quite a lot of possible configs, and before it didn't even import django. I'm using virtual env. The developer server from django works just fine both for the app and database.

```
  1 [Sun Apr 02 20:58:52.082706 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 13495] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.2rc1+.                                      
  2 [Sun Apr 02 20:58:52.082907 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 13495] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.2.                                         
  3 [Sun Apr 02 20:58:52.104626 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13495] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.4.2 configu    red -- resuming normal operations                                                                                                       
  4 [Sun Apr 02 20:58:52.104798 2017] [core:notice] [pid 13495] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'                                  
  5 [Sun Apr 02 21:00:18.727276 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 13499] [remote 192.168.1.106:0] mod_wsgi (pid=13499): Target WSGI script '/home/pi/d    jangoProjects/pidjay/pidjay/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.                                                                 
  6 [Sun Apr 02 21:00:18.727660 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 13499] [remote 192.168.1.106:0] mod_wsgi (pid=13499): Exception occurred processing     WSGI script '/home/pi/djangoProjects/pidjay/pidjay/wsgi.py'.                                                                            
  7 [Sun Apr 02 21:00:18.727938 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 13499] [remote 192.168.1.106:0] Traceback (most recent call last):                  
  8 [Sun Apr 02 21:00:18.729807 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 13499] [remote 192.168.1.106:0]   File "/home/pi/djangoProjects/pidjay/venv/lib/pyth    on3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 25, in <module>                                                             
  9 [Sun Apr 02 21:00:18.729866 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 13499] [remote 192.168.1.106:0]     import MySQLdb as Database                      
 10 [Sun Apr 02 21:00:18.730794 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 13499] [remote 192.168.1.106:0]   File "/home/pi/djangoProjects/pidjay/venv/lib/pyth    on3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>                                                                          
 11 [Sun Apr 02 21:00:18.730848 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 13499] [remote 192.168.1.106:0]     import _mysql                                   
 12 [Sun Apr 02 21:00:18.731024 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 13499] [remote 192.168.1.106:0] ImportError: No module named '_mysql'
```

Now the config from sites-available folder:

```
<Directory /home/pi/djangoProjects/pidjay/pidjay>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess pidjay python-path=/home/pi/djangoProjects/pidjay:/home/pi/djangoProjects/pidjay/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup pidjay
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/djangoProjects/pidjay/pidjay/wsgi.py
```

As You can see I specified the virtual env folder with a colon, other ways resulted in django being impossible to import. The python in the environment is ver 3.5 (checked twice), with sqlclient and django installed. When I try to import "_mysql" in python interpreter inside venv (activated) it works just fine.

This is databases setting from project's settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': "pidjay",
    "USER": "user",
    "PASSWORD": "password"
}}
```

And as I said it works on development server. Please help me with this and great thank You in advance! I will be happy to provide any additional info!

Comment: Your mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 3.4. Your Python virtual environment is Python 3.5. You cannot mix versions like that. Recreate you Python virtual environment with Python 3.4, or reinstall mod_wsgi so it is compiled for Python 3.5.

Comment: That was right! Thank You very much, did not spot that in the logs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out above, this is one way to do it.

```
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.5.14.tar.gz
tar -zxvf 4.5.14.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-4.5.14
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.5
make
make install
chmod 755 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in version mismatch as Graham kindly pointed out. After compiling mod_wsgi for python 3.5 with with the help of official docs and loading it into apache it worked as expected.